# ¿Por qué se tiene que instanciar la clase principal "Program objeto = new Program();" para acceder a función/método?

Tags: c#

Estoy usando aplicación de consola en C#, en donde en el método Main escribo todo mi código, pero fuera del método main realicé una función/método para mandarla llamar en el método Main. El punto es que investigué, y encontré que se debe de instanciar la clase principal para acceder a los métodos/funciones estén fuera del Main, pero lo que quiero saber es por qué se necesita instanciar la clase principal para acceder a ellos.
Ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace consolaPrueba
{
 class Program
 {
    Int64 numero(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)
    {
        Int64 resultado = 0;

        resultado = val1 * val2;
        return resultado;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Program objeto = new Program();
       Int64 result = objeto.numero(5,10);
       Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

 }
}
```

Mi función/método es "numero", y en el Main realizo la instancia para finalmente llamarlo así "objeto.numero(parámetro1, parámetro2);".

Funciona correctamente, pero tengo la inquietud de qué es lo que realiza al hacer dicha instancia, ya que intenté llamarla sin la instancia como normalmente lo hacía en otros lenguajes y no funcionaba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En tu caso tienes que instanciarla porque la función **Int64 numero(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)** está definida como privada al omitir el ámbito de la misma (no aparece ni **protected**, ni **private** ni **public**, ni **static** delante del tipo de tu función **Int64**) por tanto solo puede ser llamada desde una instancia de la clase que la implementa. Si lo que quieres es usarla sin instanciarla por lo que pude ver dentro del método Main solo debes establecerla como **static**.

```
static Int64 numero(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)
{
    Int64 resultado = 0;

    resultado = val1 * val2;
    return resultado;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{       
   Int64 result = numero(5,10);
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: no es privada por defecto?

Comment: uff jajaaj my mistake.

Comment: entonces solo puede ser llamada desde dentro de su misma clase. como se explica que aca se llame desde afuera?

Comment: ese comportamiento para mi es extraño pero ya lo comrpobé, te explico como: Hice una función void sin especificar el ámbito dentro de una clase Form, luego en el evento onClick de un botón cree una nueva instancia de la clase Form donde estoy y pude llamar a la función sin que de error.

Comment: entonces abria que averiguar porque hace eso, cual es el concepto detras de eso, y volver a contestar la pregutna, ya que creo que esa es la respuesta ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación @DarielRamosDíazVillegas , me fue muy útil saber eso, ya que a veces uno se encuentra información sin la explicación del porqué se debe de hacer de tal forma. PD. No puedo marcar tu respuesta como la indicada a causa de mis puntos de reputación( Soy nuevo aquí  ). Y también gracias gbianchi por las observaciones.

Comment: Algún dia regresarás a ello jajaja.

Comment: @valle deberias poder marcar la reapuesta como aceptada. Para rso no se necesita reputacion.

Comment: El problema no es el modificador de acceso, si no que no es estática. No se puede llamar a un método no estático sin crear una instancia de la clase que lo contiene.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, creo que se podria agregar algo a la parte de "por tanto solo puede ser llamada desde una instancia de la clase que la implementa", ya que si la instancia de la clase que la implementa llama al metodo afuera del scope donde la clase se esta definiendo esto resulta tambien en un error de acceso

Answer (score 5):

> Tengo la inquietud de qué es lo que realiza al hacer dicha instancia.

Las definiciones de clases (lo contenido en `class Nombre {}`) son los planos para construir un objeto, no el objeto en si.

Como analogía imagina que tienes los planos de una furgoneta, ¿puedes usar los planos para hacer una mudanza?, La verdad, no lo creo. Necesitarás construir la furgoneta en base a los planos y después usar la furgoneta para la mudanza:

```
   Furgoneta mi_furgoneta = new Furgoneta();
// ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <----- Construyo mi furgoneta
//  ^         ^
//   \         \----- Esta será mi furgoneta
//    \
//     \---Tengo los planos de una furgoneta

// Después de construir mi furgoneta, puedo usarla.
mi_furgoneta.cargar();
mi_furgoneta.desplazarse();
mi_furgoneta.descargar();
```

Comment: Muy buena explicación @Paula_plus_plus , me quedó aún más claro. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Respuesta original: 

El metodo main es un metodo estatico, por lo cual pertenece a la clase Program, entonces no hace falta crear una instancia para llamarlo.
Mientras que el metodo que creaste no es estatico, por lo tanto necesita un objeto que lo llame, de manera que tenes que crear una instancia, para tener un objeto, para llamar a su metodo.
Si tienes dos objetos de una misma clase Program cada uno tiene su propio metodo numero, pero ambos tienen EL MISMO metodo Main ya que este es estatico.

---

Actualizacion:
Tras haber repsondido o anterior se planteo el interrogante "¿Pero no deberia ser el metodo inaccesible ya que es privado?" a lo cual realice la siguiente prueba:

```
using System;

namespace consolaPrueba
{
 class Program
 {
    private Int64 numero(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)
    {
        Program objeto = new Program();
        return objeto.numero2(val1,val2);
    }

    private Int64 numero2(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)
    {
        return val1 * val2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       Program objeto = new Program();

       Console.WriteLine(objeto.numero(5,10));

       Objeto.hacer();
    }

 }

 class Objeto
 {
    public static void hacer(){

       Objeto objeto2 = new Objeto();

       Console.WriteLine(objeto2.numero(5,10));
    }

    private Int64 numero(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)
    {
        Objeto objeto = new Objeto();
        return objeto.numero2(val1,val2);
    }

    private Int64 numero2(Int64 val1, Int64 val2)
    {
        return val1 * val2;
    }
 }
}
```

El cual es un programa que compila y cuya salida es `50\n50\n`, ya que los metodos privados pueden ser llamados dentro de la clase en la que han sido declarados, no importa que el metodo que los utiliza sea llamado desde afuera si el llamado al metodo privado esta escrito en la misma clase en la cual el metodo fue declarado.

Comment: y como hace para llamar a un metodo privado desde afuera de la clase?

Comment: Mira no tengo un compilador de c# a mano ahora como para hacer la prueba empierica, pero creo que si bien el tipo por defecto es private, al llamarlo desde un metodo estatico de la misma clase que creo la instancia puede que te habilite a usarlo. Pero tampoco estoy seguro de este caso, puede que te este creando los metodos como `internal`

Comment: @gbianchi ahi he editado la respuesta con una nueva prueba y mas informacion al respecto

Comment: De igual manera muchas gracias @Sacha por tu aportación. La tomaré en cuenta.